# Not able to see the "Junit Test cases" in Eclipse for making Robitum Test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, robotium

I am new to Java & Eclipse as well JUNIT, Robotium Automation.
Issue i see that i was watching Youtube Video to setup an automated test for one of the project.
Once you create a test project for the android app project, copy the robotium JARS, Create the Junit Test Case by Right click on Test Project --> we should be able to see the Junit Test Case to create. But on my Eclipse IDE i couldnt see anything.

any guide in usage of Robotium to build automation testing?

Can you please help - What is that am missing badly?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have adt plugin installed, android sdk configured?

Comment: Hi Maszter Thanks for reply. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html - i have followed the ADT plugin install procedure and i have installted. however after installing the plugin we need to configure the ADT with eclipse following the below steps ->Once Eclipse restarts, you must specify the location of your Android SDK directory:
In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears, select Use existing SDKs.
Browse and select the location of the Android SDK directory you recently downloaded and unpacked.
Click Next. i was unable to perform above pls guide.